# Unable to use webservice axis2 on jboss 51GA

Tags: web-services, jboss, apache-axis

I developed a web-service on eclipse with tomcat 7 and jdk7 and axis2 and i have to deploy it on jboss51GA and jdk5 and i get the flowing error when i tried to access web-service:
This Web axisService has deployment faults

```
Error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pachet/clasa_ws : Unsupported
major.minor version 51.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:82) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:277) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) at
org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.load
```

I deployed the web-service as war file and is not in the axis directory.
Can anyone help me with this problem that i face for a week..

Answer (score 0):

```
Some Condition to be followed in eclipse

1.Eclipse Dynamice Module version should be 2.5 or less 
2.In Configuration select axis2 (if not there if install axis2)


For JBoss need to have a Maven Project and Jboss version less than 7
```